# ViewPager with FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

My adapter works fine but my fragment views are not inflated.
My main activity:

```
package com.example.rishi.flipper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    viewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout= (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter viewpageradapter= new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewpageradapter.addFragment(new Fragone(),"One");
    viewpageradapter.addFragment(new FragTwo(),"Two");
    viewpageradapter.addFragment(FragTwo.newInstance(),"Two");
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewpageradapter);

}
}
```

The resource of the main activity :
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    >
 <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="Toolbar"
     android:height="24sp"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    ></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And here's my adapter:

```
package com.example.rishi.flipper;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager; 
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
ArrayList<Fragment> array=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> title=new ArrayList<>();
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager) {
    super(supportFragmentManager);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    return array.get(position);
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String text) {
    array.add(fragment);
    title.add(text);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return array.size();

}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return title.get(position);
}
}
```

I'm using Layout inflater to inflate a text view in fragment.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewPager` cannot `wrap_content` for it's height as it can't know the maximum height of all of its children, as they may not all be instantiated at the same time (`ViewPager` creates and destroys its children as needed when scrolling between pages). It is possible changing to `match_parent` will fix this issue.

***It is also a very bad idea to hold an `ArrayList` of `Fragment`s as this will inevitably cause a memory leak, and crashes after process death in production.*** The intended behaviour for `ViewPager` is that you instantiate the fragments in `getItem` as they are needed.

If, after both of these changes, it still isn't inflating anything, it's likely that the issue is in the `onCreateView` code of your fragments.